# Character count in a textarea

Tags: jquery, count, character

I don't know how to create a jquery function that counts how many times a given character (for example the letter "b", lowcase) is repeated inside an element of the page (in my case a preformatted div).

Any suggestions?

Comment: What have you tried? You'll get a much better response here if you can show that you've at least made an attempt to solve your own problem before you ask others to give you answers.

Comment: parse the page and use regex.test(page) to count the matches

Comment: var str = $('pre').html();
alert(str.split('b').length-1);
could it be ok?

Answer (score 2):

A functional approach with lease line of code to send any character to search:-***

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
    console.log(getCharCount('b'));// send any character
  });
});

function getCharCount(search){
 return  $('textarea').val().toLowerCase().match(new RegExp(search, 'g')).length; // to check both lowercase case-uppercase presence
 //return ($('textarea').val().match(new RegExp(search, 'g')).length; // for lowercase match only
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>

<button>count b</button>
```

Comment: `.toLowerCase()` should be appended after `.val()`.

Comment: @MD.KhairulBasar  sorry, editing mistake. Corrected that.Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 2):

Do like below:-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
     var countB = $('textarea').val().toUpperCase().match(/B/g); 
     if(countB){
      console.log(countB);
      console.log(countB.length);
     } 
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>

<button>count b</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Reusable for any letter...

```js
    function charCount (array, character) {
        // Keep a running total.
        var count = 0;
        // Loop over the array.
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            // If the character matches, increment the count.
            if (array[i] === character) {
                count ++
            }
        }
        // Return the count when the loop has finished.
        return count;
    }

    // Push the characters into an array.
    var letterArray = $('.text').text().toLowerCase().split('');

    // Pass the array and chosen letter to the function
    alert(charCount( letterArray, 'b' )) // 3
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="text">Bubbles</textarea>
```